# Muc light not working due to service not available

Tags: swift, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I am trying to implement muc light in iOS application with Mongoseim Server. For group chat I am using muclight but when I discover my services by:

```
let toStr: String = XMPPConstants.ConnectionHost // my xmpp connection host

        let query = XMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#item")
        let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: XMPPJID(string: toStr), elementID: xmppStream.generateUUID(), child: query)
        iq?.addAttribute(withName: "from", stringValue: xmppStream.myJID.bare())


        xmppStream.send(iq)
```

I am getting the response with error like:

```
<error type='cancel'>
    <service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
```

Please help me how to resolve this error. 
Do I need to configure the server part or something else ?

Please explain in detail.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `ejabberd.cfg` file for mucLight.file can be found id `[MongooseIM root]/rel/mongooseim/etc/`

```
{mod_muc_light, [
    {backend, odbc},
    {host, "muclight.@HOST@"},
    {rooms_per_user,infinity},
    {max_occupants,infinity},
    {rooms_per_page,infinity},
    {all_can_configure,true},{all_can_invite, true}]},
```

for more information please follow this link [mod_muc_light](http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_muc_light/)